# Find Top X most similar users, based on Y boolean attributes

Tags: c#, similarity, information-retrieval

Let's say I have 5 users, each with 5 boolean attributes, which could look like this:

```
        | A   B   C   D   E
 --------------------------
 User 0 | 1   1   0   1   0
 User 1 | 0   1   0   1   0
 User 2 | 0   0   1   0   1
 User 3 | 1   1   0   0   0
 User 4 | 0   0   0   1   0
```

Now what would be the best approach to get a list of the top x users with the most "trues" in common. So in the example above the ranking should look like his:

```
Top 1: Users 0 (most true attributes)
Top 2: Users 0 and 1 OR Users 0 and 3 (both pairs have 2 attributes in common)
Top 3: Users 0, 1 and 3
Top 4: Users 0, 1, 3 and 4
Top 5: Users 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I know there are metrics and distance measures to tell how similar two users are, but i want a list of most similar ones. Should i use some kind of clustering algorithm? But which one would consider multiple binary attributes and how could I implement it (preferably in C#)?

Since I haven't taken any classes on data mining, the literature on this topic is kinda overwhelming, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what is special about User 0 has the most.  You can just do a simple loop.

Comment: I maybe asking a stupid question, but what format is the data in, lists, arrays , a database, some funky clustered google big data magical format?

Comment: `OrderBy(x => x.A - x.B - x.C - x.D - x.E);`

Comment: @SteveHarris this would work if there wasn't "*in common*" in OP's question. And even there, `x.A` should be `-x.A` or the whole sentence should be `OrderByDescending(x => x.A + x.B + x.C + x.D + x.E)`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
@paparazzo for the context in which I need this for it is the most logic thing to to, but a "Top 1" doesn't make sense anyways.

Comment: @MichaelRandall the data is essentially in nested Lists and needed to be evaluated to have such a simple representation as in my example

Comment: This is a similarity search task, no clustering here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User mostTrueUser = Users
        .OrderByDescending(u => (u.A?1:0) + (u.B?1:0) + (u.C?1:0) + (u.D?1:0) + (u.E?1:0))
        .First();

var groups = Users.GroupBy(u => ((u.A && mostTrueUser.A)?1:0)
                               +((u.B && mostTrueUser.B)?1:0)
                               +((u.C && mostTrueUser.C)?1:0)
                               +((u.D && mostTrueUser.D)?1:0)
                               +((u.E && mostTrueUser.E)?1:0)
                          ,u => u).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key);
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  // following have {0} 'true' in common with {1}",
                      group.Key,
                      mostTrueUser.ID);
    foreach(var g in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + g.ID);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following:

```
3   // following have 3 'true' in common with 0
  0
2   // following have 2 'true' in common with 0
  1
  3
1   // following have 1 'true' in common with 0
  4
0   // following have 0 'true' in common with 0
  2
```

---

### Explanations

I used `u.A?1:0` so `true` becomes `1` and `false` becomes `0`.
I then got the User with most `true` using `OrderByDescending([sum of trues])`.
Then the `GroupBy` is used to group all Users on the number of `true` in common with the `mostTrueUser`.

---

Your ranking seems a little bit more complicated, but you can start with this to solve it.

---

I wrote a little tweak:

```
public class UserRank
{
    public User UserA{get;set;}
    public User UserB{get;set;}
    public int Compare{
        get{return ((UserA.A && UserB.A)?1:0)
                  +((UserA.B && UserB.B)?1:0)
                  +((UserA.C && UserB.C)?1:0)
                  +((UserA.D && UserB.D)?1:0)
                  +((UserA.E && UserB.E)?1:0);}
    }
}
```

and then:

```
List<UserRank> userRanks = new List<UserRank>();
for(int i=0;i<Users.Count;i++)
{
    for(int j=i;j<Users.Count;j++)
    {
        userRanks.Add(new UserRank
        {
            UserA = Users[i],
            UserB = Users[j]
        });
    }
}

var groups = userRanks.GroupBy(u => u.Compare, u => u).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} in common:",group.Key);

    foreach(var u in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}-{1}",u.UserA.ID,u.UserB.ID);
    }
}
```

gives me:

```
3 in common:
  0-0
2 in common:
  0-1
  0-3
  1-1
  2-2
  3-3
1 in common:
  0-4
  1-3
  1-4
  4-4
0 in common:
  0-2
  1-2
  2-3
  2-4
  3-4
```

[TutorialsPoint CodingGround permalink for testing purpose](http://tpcg.io/LBTu0s)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
You pretty much showed me, that I was thinking way too complicated. In the end I used a very similar approach to yours. I find the user with most trues, calculate the similarity to every other user and pick the Top x of this ordered list.

Comment: @user3262883 yeah that's what my first approach looks like :)